# How to check that username password is correct using curl command?

Tags: curl

I want to be able to write a curl command where in i pass options like username password in the curl itself and it should connect to the server. Is there a way where we can find if the user is able to connect to that mentioned server? That means it should throw some error while I run the curl, if the credentials are incorrect. I was trying the below :-

```
curl --silent -k --digest -u "admin:admin" "https://theservername.com:8010"
```

But this return nothing.

Comment: The server should send a `401 Unauthorized` header if the password is incorrect, or a `200 OK` header otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `man curl` the reason you're getting no response is `--silent`, as expected:

```
Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter  or  error  mes‐
          sages.   Makes  Curl mute. It will still output the data you ask
          for, potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect
          it.
```

If you don't want the progress meter, the likely reason you chose to add `--silent`, but you want to see the error messages then you must use `-S` additionally.